# Getting error as: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    i = 0
    j = 0
    flag = 0
    S = 2
    E = 10
    for i in range(S, E + 1):
        if (i == 1):
            continue
        flag = 1
        for j in range(2, i // 2 + 1):
            if (i % j == 0):
                flag = 0
                break
        if (flag == 1):
            print(list(i))
```

I need to find the length of the total integers between an interval and for this code. I am getting an error

Comment: `i` is integer in the range `S` to `E+1` may be you need just `print(i)` instead of `print(list(i))`?

Comment: `list(i)` is not the equivalent of `[i]`.

Comment: printing i gives all the integers between S and E, whereas, I need a single integer value of the total number of integers between S and E

Answer (score 1):

Well error is comming becose you are trying to list through an intiger.
In **for** loop **i** is an intiger(int).

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to convert an `int` object to a `list` object.

If you want to create a list with every value of `i` in every iteration, you can gradually add the `i` value to a list.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    example = []
    i = 0
    j = 0
    flag = 0
    S = 2
    E = 10
    for i in range(S, E + 1):
        if (i == 1):
            continue
        flag = 1
        for j in range(2, i // 2 + 1):
            if (i % j == 0):
                flag = 0
                break
        if (flag == 1):
            example.append(i)
    print(example)
```

Answer (score -1):

The error is with this line

```
print(list(i))
```

Change this line to:-

```
print(list(str(i)))
```

You were getting error because python cannot list an integer(int) , you to change it to string using str().

if you got the answer, then please accept it and upvote it.

Thank You